# Php advanced include different pages with the same variables

Tags: php

I am trying to include different pages on one page. However the problem that iam having is that i use the same variables on all the pages and therefore there is a mess and the tables and graphs that re included dont work.

Dose anybody have an idea of how i could get over this problem and be able to include the pages without having to go and change all the variables ?

Comment: As makuraYami said you're better of working with classes etc. And since you tagged your question as PHP5 you might want to do some reading on how to OOP, because by the sounds of it you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unset()` the variables after they have been used in one included file and before you include the next file.

For example:

```
include 'file1.php';

unset($variable1, $variable2, $variable3);

include 'file2.php';
```

Comment: this seems to work for me , iam sure there is a better way like with clasess like mentioned above

Comment: Working with classes is indeed a better way. But if you'd prefer not to change the name of your variables then I guess you'd prefer not to have to restructure all your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. Work with classes if you wish to keep variables to one page.

else you will have to rename the variables with a prefix of where they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

you can unset all your variables before starting of the each page.

Answer (score 0):

If those variables are changing in the includes somewhere why don't you simply clone a variable and use that in the includes instead of the original variable.

Or perhaps even better make sure those variables don't change in the includes.

It's hard to tell (without code), but it sounds like You're doing it wrong.